# sunspot - returning rows found in one table only and not in another

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2, sunspot

I am using sunspot solr for in my rails app.

I have 2 tables, Table A and Table B. Table A contain ids which appears also in B.

I need to display and perform searches on only only rows found in Table A and not in table B. 
The searchable attributes are defined as the following in the model.rb:

```
  searchable do

    text  :bk_id
    long  :bk_id

    long :tableb_bk_id do
      tableb.nil?? '' : (tableb.bk_id.nil? ? '' : tableb.bk_id)
    end
  end
```

How do I filter the results so that all search and default search return rows with ids found in Table A only and not found in B.

Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are the steps I took to solve the above problem.

Step 1: Find all rows in Table A which need to be excluded

Step 2: Do somethig similar to the following code

```
  post = Post.find(params[:id])
Sunspot.search(Post) do
  without(post)
end
```

The `without` clause will exclude the rows you don't want to appear in the resultset.

Hope this is of help to somebody